Convert energy consumption sessions to hourly energy consumption timeseries in python
I have a dataframe with start and end timestamps, duration in HH:MM:SS and energy consumed. A sample is shown below:
                    start                    end        time   energy
0     2024-03-30 22:01:25    2024-03-31 12:29:07    00:18:21     2.18
1     2024-03-30 19:56:42    2024-03-30 22:00:23    02:03:36    14.79
2     2024-03-30 19:49:00    2024-03-30 19:56:40    00:07:37     0.89

I want to convert this data into an timeseries that shows my energy consumption on an hourly basis over time. An example of the desired outcome is shown below:
                     time  energy
0     2024-03-31 00:00:00     0.0
1     2024-03-30 23:00:00     0.0
2     2024-03-30 22:00:00    2.23
3     2024-03-30 21:00:00    7.18
4     2024-03-30 20:00:00    7.18
5     2024-03-30 19:00:00    1.28

I'm new to pandas so the path to a solution is not at all obvious to me.

I'm not sure you have the right information to be able to do this accurately, unless you know or assume that the rate of energy consumption is the same over each time period. For example, in your sample data index 1, how do know how much of the energy consumption occurred during each hour? Couldn't the usage be higher in one minute and less the next? What if 13/14 energy units used over the whole time period were consumed in the first few minutes? You could make a guess and spread it out linearly, but I'm not sure if that's going to give you an accurate picture.

As someone with limited experience with Pandas, I'd manually create a new dataframe and add the rows one at a time.
If you keep track of which input rows you have already processed, you only need to go through the input dataframe a single time to fill the output dataframe.

You can try (I'm assuming the first end timestamp should be 2024-03-31 00:29:07 <- we count day from the 00:00:00):
buckets = dict.fromkeys(
    pd.date_range(df.start.min().floor("1h"), df.end.max(), freq="1h"), 0
)

for start, time, energy in zip(df.start, df.time, df.energy):
    td = pd.Timedelta(time)
    dr = pd.date_range(start.floor("1h"), start + td, freq="1h")

    if len(dr) == 1:
        buckets[dr[0]] += energy
    else:
        for i, b in enumerate(dr):
            if i == 0:
                s = (b + pd.Timedelta("1h") - start).seconds
            elif i == len(dr) - 1:
                s = (start + td - b).seconds
            else:
                s = 60 * 60

            buckets[b] += (s / td.seconds) * energy

out = pd.DataFrame({"time": buckets.keys(), "energy": buckets.values()}).sort_values(
    by="time", ascending=False
)
print(out)

Prints:
                 time    energy
5 2024-03-31 00:00:00  0.000000
4 2024-03-30 23:00:00  0.000000
3 2024-03-30 22:00:00  2.215898
2 2024-03-30 21:00:00  7.179612
1 2024-03-30 20:00:00  7.179612
0 2024-03-30 19:00:00  1.284879


I would create a pandas series for each second in time along with the per-second energy usage. Then you can use the .resample method on the timeseries to show usage over any frequency, with second-level granularity. In this case, we assume a linear per-second usage over the time periods of the input data.
start = df.start.min()
end = df.end.max()
seconds_index = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='1s')
seconds_data = {ts: 0 for ts in seconds_index}
for row in df.itertuples():
    row_start = row.start
    row_end = row.end
    num_seconds = (row_end - row_start).seconds
    energy_per_second = row.energy / num_seconds
    for sec in pd.date_range(row_start, row_end, freq='1s')[:-1]:
        seconds_data[sec] += energy_per_second

usage_per_second = pd.Series(seconds_data, index=seconds_index)

# resample the timeseries by hour, rather than seconds:
usage_per_hour = usage_per_second.resample('1h').sum()

You could also easily resample to other frequencies this way, too:
usage_per_minute = usage_per_second.resample('1min').sum()

However, as noted, we're making an assumption that the rate of consumption is constant in each period of the input data and using that to fill the per-second data points.
